# Apex page. No records was display when creating table

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I'm new with Salesforce. I'm trying to create a page that would list the field from my existing object.  the problem is it does not display any record.

```
<apex:page standardController="ISG_User_Survey__c">

<apex:pageBlock title="Closed Incident">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ISG_User_Survey__c}" var="ci">
<apex:column value="{!ci.Incident_No__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!ci.Client_Name__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!ci.Title__c }"/>
<apex:column >  
    <apex:form >
        <span> Rate Us: </span>
        <apex:inputField value="{!ISG_User_Survey__c.Rating__c}"/>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>       
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

#### Here's the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PageBlockTables have to repeat through a list of records, they cannot be bound to a single record.  To display a single record in a table, you'd either need an Apex Extension or just use HTML like below.
BTW, you don't have a button to save the record.

```
<apex:page standardController="ISG_User_Survey__c">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Closed Incident">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Incident #</th><th>Client Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Rate Us</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{!ci.Incident_No__c}</td><td>{!ci.Client_Name__c}</td><td>{!ci.Title__c}</td><td>
          <apex:inputField value="{!ISG_User_Survey__c.Rating__c}"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```